# Java - Apache Commons HttpClient throws a NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, exception, noclassdeffounderror, apache-commons-httpclient

I'm using the Apache Commons HTTP Client and I have included all the required jar files (ie commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar and commons-httpclient-3.1.jar) in the class path.

The purpose of this code is to send files (in this case images) to the content management system when a website user creates and saves a new image article.  The exception appears in the File Sender window when the filesender attempts to transfer images from the Tomcat temp folder to the CMS.  This causes the process to fail and the images remain stuck in the temp folder.

What could be the cause of this error?

```
SEVERE: Policy class "uk.co.content.article.MoodboardArticlePolicy" spec
ified by input template MoodboardArticle as top policy has a dependency
on some class where runtime version is incompatible with the version compiled ag
ainst
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/RequestEnt
ity
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at com.polopoly.cm.policy.PolicyFactoryDependencyInjecting$DependencyInj
ectionPolicyInstantiator.createInstance(PolicyFactoryDependencyInjecting.java:71
)
        at com.polopoly.cm.policy.PolicyFactory.createPolicyInstance(PolicyFacto
ry.java:141)
        at com.polopoly.cm.policy.PolicyFactoryDependencyInjecting.createPolicyI
nstance(PolicyFactoryDependencyInjecting.java:49)
        at com.polopoly.cm.policy.PolicyFactory.createPolicy(PolicyFactory.java:
103)
        at com.polopoly.cm.policy.PolicyCMServerBase.getPolicyFor(PolicyCMServer
Base.java:1046)
        at com.polopoly.cm.policy.PolicyCMServerBase.getPolicyFor(PolicyCMServer
Base.java:972)
        at com.polopoly.cm.policy.PolicyCMServerBase.createNewVersion(PolicyCMSe
rverBase.java:177)
        at com.polopoly.cm.policy.PolicyCMServerBase.createNewVersion(PolicyCMSe
rverBase.java:157)
        at com.polopoly.cm.policy.PolicyCMServerBase.createContentVersion(Policy
CMServerBase.java:740)
        at com.polopoly.cm.policy.PolicyCMServerBase.createContentVersion(Policy
CMServerBase.java:754)
        at uk.co.prestige.ftpclient.FileSender.updatePolopolyContent(Fil
eSender.java:244)
        at uk.co.prestige.ftpclient.FileSender.sendFile(FileSender.java:
194)
        at uk.co.prestige.ftpclient.HotFolderWorker.notifyFileProcessLis
teners(HotFolderWorker.java:61)
        at uk.co.prestige.ftpclient.DirectoryScanner.scanNow(DirectorySc
anner.java:79)
        at uk.co.prestige.ftpclient.HotFolderWorker.run(HotFolderWorker.
java:88)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.metho
ds.RequestEntity
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 17 more
```

Comment: "commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar and commons-httpclient-3.1.jar". You don't need both. Pick one version.

Comment: At first I was only using commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar, but I still got the same error.

Comment: Have you included all the dependency Jars for the runtime classpath too?